# Functionally "wipe and reinstall" the application

Tags: android

I am currently trying to add a feature in my app in which, when the user presses a `Button`, I would like all saved data in the app to be reset (all `sharedPreferences`, all values stored in `sqlite` databases, etc.). Functionally, I would like it to be similar to an app uninstall and reinstall. Is there any command I could use that would make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

there's no built-in method on the Android framework to do that, but it's very simple to do it yourself with a little `deleteFiles(File f)` recursive method:

and call it with:

```
deleteFiles(context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir);
```

ps.: recursive means: for each `f.isDirectory()` in that folder you have to call again the same method, and for each `!f.isDirectory()` you delete it.